# Powershell iterating over lines of text throws exceptions

Tags: powershell

I am trying to parse lots of .txt files into a specific format that I will need.

The goal of the code is to:

- remove the top 39 lines of text
- remove the bottom 6 lines.
- remove the first 53 characters on the beginning of each line
- prepend the name of the file to each line.

This is my code:

```
$targetDir = "E:\home\export\"
$indexDir = "E:\index\"

Get-ChildItem -Path "$indexDir\*" -Include *.txt -Recurse | % {
    $file = $_
    $name = $file | Select -exp BaseName

    get-content $file | select -Skip 39 | select -SkipLast 6 | ForEach-Object {
        $_ = $name + "\" + $_.Remove(53, $_.Length)
    }| set-content $file+"temp"
    move $file+"temp" $file -Force
}
```

The Remove function is throwing the following exception:

```
Exception calling "Remove" with "2" argument(s): "Index and count must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: count"
At E:\create_index_stap2.ps1:9 char:9
+         $_ = $name + "\" + $_.Remove(53, $_.Length)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

The text files look like this:

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20200324111411
Username: MYPC\xorinzor
RunAs User: MYPC\xorinzor
Configuration Name: 
Machine: MYPC (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0)
Host Application: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe
Process ID: 18468
PSVersion: 5.1.17763.1007
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.17763.1007
BuildVersion: 10.0.17763.1007
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is E:\index\filename.7z.txt

7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 29931544 bytes (29 MiB)

Listing archive: E:\home\export\filename.7z

--
Path = E:\home\export\filename.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 29931544
Headers Size = 2281
Method = LZMA2:24
Solid = +
Blocks = 1

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2018-03-17 11:14:44 D....            0            0  Contacts
2018-03-17 13:38:06 D....            0            0  Desktop
2018-03-17 13:22:04 D....            0            0  Documents
2018-02-06 14:14:28 D....            0            0  Documents\Some directory
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2018-12-16 07:36:34           43367240     29929263  79 files, 37 folders
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20200324111411
**********************
```

Basically, if the textfile in this case is named "filename.7z.txt" I want to end up with the following filecontent:

```
filename.7z\Contacts
filename.7z\Desktop
filename.7z\Documents
filename.7z\Documents\Some directory
```

Why is my code throwing an exception?

Comment: The second parameter argument (the `count`) to `String.Remove()` is the length of the resulting substring, not the original (hence the error), and it'll also remove _from_ index 53, not up to. You want `String.Substring()` instead. `$line.Remove(53, $line.Length)` -> `$line.Substring(53)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen makes sense, but using `$_.Substring(53)` says the startindex can't be larger then the string length. I think the lines aren't properly getting iterated, but am not sure why not.

Comment: `$_.Substring([Math]::Min($_.Length, 53))` then :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen now I'm getting the error `move : Cannot find path 'E:\index\filename.7z.txt+temp' because it does not exist`. The stringlength should always be larger then 53, so this leads me to believe the foreach-object code is incorrect, but I can't spot the problem.

Comment: Change all instances of `$file+"temp"` to `"${file}temp"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That resulted in `move : Cannot find path 'E:\index\filename.7z.txttemp' because it does not exist.`. I'm so sorry haha

Comment: You are piping nothing into your `set-content` from your `foreach-object`. You need to restructure that part or remove the `$_ = `

Comment: I ended up adding `Write-Output $line` within the `foreach-object`, and I also figured out that in order to perform string methods on `$_` I need to encapsulate it with quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems to do what you want. [*grin*]

however, since this is from a transcript it looks likely to be easier to just re-run the code to get the desired user folders ... perhaps add an export to CSV or CliXml so you can re-import the data as needed later.

the code seems to be well enuf commented. if you have questions, please ask ... [*grin*]

```
#region >>> fake reading in a text file as an array of lines
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20200324111411
Username: MYPC\xorinzor
RunAs User: MYPC\xorinzor
Configuration Name: 
Machine: MYPC (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0)
Host Application: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe
Process ID: 18468
PSVersion: 5.1.17763.1007
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.17763.1007
BuildVersion: 10.0.17763.1007
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is E:\index\filename.7z.txt

7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 29931544 bytes (29 MiB)

Listing archive: E:\home\export\filename.7z

--
Path = E:\home\export\filename.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 29931544
Headers Size = 2281
Method = LZMA2:24
Solid = +
Blocks = 1

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2018-03-17 11:14:44 D....            0            0  Contacts
2018-03-17 13:38:06 D....            0            0  Desktop
2018-03-17 13:22:04 D....            0            0  Documents
2018-02-06 14:14:28 D....            0            0  Documents\Some directory
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2018-12-16 07:36:34           43367240     29929263  79 files, 37 folders
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20200324111411
**********************
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> fake reading in a text file as an array of lines

# set the file name prefix
$FileName = 'A_FileName.7z'

# grab the lines starting at the 39th item [array indexes start with zero]
#    & ending 6 lines before the end
$Results = $InStuff[38..($InStuff.GetUpperBound(0) - 6)].
    ForEach({
        # replace the 1st 53 chars with nothing
        $_ -replace '^.{53}', ''
        }).
    # trim away any leading/trailing spaces
    Trim().
    ForEach({
        # concatenate the file name with the remainder of each line
        "$FileName\$_"
        })

# display on screen
$Results
```

output ...

```
A_FileName.7z\Contacts
A_FileName.7z\Desktop
A_FileName.7z\Documents
A_FileName.7z\Documents\Some directory
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify the script to instead of using the split, it removes the first 53 characters of each line? The filesize wont always be 0, and this ends up breaking the script unfortunately. Whereas the prepended information is always 53 characters long.

Comment: @xorinzor - yep! i should have thot of that. [*blush*] i otta have the code tested & updated in about 5 minutes.

Comment: @xorinzor - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]